# What's a good long-exposure app for the iPhone?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, photos, camera

I'm looking for an app that lets me take long exposures of 10 seconds or more. This can either be one long exposure, or multiple shorter exposures, like 0.5 seconds, combined together by the app.

This is on the iPhone 5s running iOS 8. Not jailbroken, and don't intend to.

The app needs to have a timer to avoid camera shake caused by pressing the shutter button.

Comment: Do you have a jailbreak? and what iOS version are you running?

Comment: Are you looking for something like Slow Shutter Cam (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slow-shutter-cam/id357404131?mt=8)?

Comment: Thanks. Slow Shutter Cam doesn't work for me. I seem to get blown out highlights in Low-light mode even with an exposure of just 1 sec. I contacted the developer, who didn't respond after a week or two, so I have to look for other apps. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll not get the same result using 1 pict of 5s than 10 picts of 0.5s...

Comment: not sure if you're trying to increase light capture/exposure, or movement.  did you try the other app by slowshutter's author? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/night-modes/id572215621?mt=8

Comment: That's also limited to 0.5s, which I realized only after posting the question. That's apparently a limit imposed by the platform -- iOs 7 running on the iPhone 5s. However, now that I upgraded to iOS 8, I'm again looking for a suitable app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [NightCap](http://www.nightcapcamera.com). Did you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but it unfortunately has the same limit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on iOS 8, the new camera API made possible by Apple allows true manual exposure control over the pictures taken. I would suggest [Manual - Custom exposure camera](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/manual-custom-exposure-camera/id917146276?mt=8&uo=4&at=11lMu5). It's a really good replacement for the native camera app as well.